# Mysql intersection of datetimes

Tags: php, mysql

I have the table `Vacation` in mysql DB. The table has `datetime_from` and `datetime_to`. To have a vacation from Monday to Friday means there is only one record in the table with two timestamps

- `date_from` = `'MONDAY_DATE 00:00:00'`
- `date_to` = `'FRIDAY_DATE 23:59:59'`

The working time is from 8:00 to 16:00 every day. I would like to get all the working time that employee missed during his vacation (in hours for example). It's 8hrs a day x 5.

Im able to do that in 5 queries (one for every day and then sum up with PHP) as an intersection of date intervals BUT **is it possible to perform it in only one mysql query**?

Comment: I don't know that you could do this with a query, but you could write a procedure to do it.  I'm not sure it it's better than your PHP script, though.

Comment: Here is a [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771270/date-range-intersection-in-sql) to something similar but when I want to avoid to apply this 5 times...

Answer (score 0):

> SELECT SUM(date_to - date_from) as `seconds_missed` FROM `Vacation`
>   WHERE ...

That would give you the total number of seconds missed for an employee assuming the where clause matches it against a given user. I guess you could also add conditions in your where clause to only grab dates in a certain range (i.e. worked missed that week).

Comment: If this suggestion is totally out of bounds then maybe I understood your question incorrectly.